# Efficient way of deploying GeoServer WMS and getting wms-url as a result

Tags: geoserver, wms, cloud-gis

I created a GeoServer WMS that runs well on localhost. Now I want to deploy the GeoServer in order to make it work for externals. The goal is to have a classic wms-url that I can share with friends from around the world and they just insert the URL in their QGIS or ArcGIS. What is the best method here? (I have little experience with deploying)

Comment: You just need a public facing web server

Comment: And set the proxy URL on the global page.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works